# Constructing a member object inside the parent class' constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor

I am currently learning OOP for a project I'm working on (I'm in highschool and have some experience with c++; this is my third 'large' (>3 months) c++ project.) I have the basics of C++ classes figured out and managed to make some of the classes for the project.

So these is my page.h header:

```
class cl_Page{
public:
  cl_Page(cl_LessonMoment *parent_param);
  cl_Page(cl_SoftRoot *parent_param);
  int parent_type;
  cl_LessonMoment *parent_lmoment;
  cl_SoftRoot *parent_softroot;

  char id[256];

  //<content>
  //Backgrounds.
  str_Color bgcolor;
  cl_Image bgimage;

  //Actual content
  vector<cl_Textbox> textboxes;
  vector<cl_Button> buttons;
  vector<cl_Image> images;
  //</content>
};
```

(include guards and such are not here, but they are in my project)

And this is my page.cpp:

```
cl_Page::cl_Page(cl_LessonMoment *parent_param){
  parent_lmoment = parent_param;
  parent_type = 1;
  id[0] = '\0';
  //bgimage(NULL);
  SetColor(bgcolor, 0x000000ff);
}
```

(the other constructor is similar, it just sets a different type of parent)

My problem is that I want to call the constructor to bgimage (which is of cl_Image class type) inside my cl_Page constructor. If I try this (uncomment the line in the constructor), obviously it won't work.

So yeah, how do I call the constructor now? I really need to construct every member along with the cl_Page object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create `bgImage` object in `cl_Page` constructor, it has to be either a pointer (1) or you should use a constructor's initialization list (2), which in this case would probably be a better solution for you.

**1.** - Field is a pointer to cl_Image

```
bgImage = new cl_Image(nullptr);
```

**2.** - Use of constructor's initialization list

```
cl_Page::cl_Page(cl_LessonMoment *parent_param) :
      bgImage(nullptr) 
{
  parent_lmoment = parent_param;
  parent_type = 1;
  id[0] = '\0';
  SetColor(bgcolor, 0x000000ff);
}
```

There you can read more about constructor's initialization list: http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize variable using an member initialization list:

```
cl_Page::cl_Page(cl_LessonMoment *parent_param)
: bgImage(NULL)
{
  parent_lmoment = parent_param;
  parent_type = 1;
  id[0] = '\0';
  SetColor(bgcolor, 0x000000ff);
}
```

In fact, this is the preferred way to set data in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
cl_Page::cl_Page(cl_LessonMoment *parent_param)
    : bgImage( nullptr )
{
  parent_lmoment = parent_param;
  parent_type = 1;
  id[0] = '\0';
  SetColor(bgcolor, 0x000000ff);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your member like that:

```
cl_Page::cl_Page(cl_LessonMoment *parent_param)
: parent_lmoment(parent_param)
, parent_type(1)
, bgimage(NULL)
{
    id[0] = '\0';
    SetColor(bgcolor, 0x000000ff);
}
```

Initializing the pointer in the constructor's head this isn't necessary, but I'd still recommend it.
I'd also suggest initializing the other pointer with 0, it might help you if you run into bugs ;-)